# Decoding base64 string is going wrong in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, base64

The context is as follows: I wrote an app which can choose an image from your library and then it converts the image into base64 string as follows:

```
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!, 0.1)! as NSData
    let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

Here myImageView is where the image is stored when one chooses an image. Then I uploaded this into my local mysql database, where I have column of type MEDIUMTEXT. Then I wrote an app that could get this string from the database, but when I wanted to decode it and make it a UIimage again, my program failed. This is what I tried:

```
    let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: tempString64, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
```

Here tempString64 is the string that I got from the database (I also checked that it is not empty). If I run the app I get an error that dataDecoded was nil while trying to unwrap it. I really don't understand why it is nil, while my tempString is really there.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I tried many things, but it is not working! Here is the relevant part of the code that I use now inside URLSession:

```
   if data != nil {
            do {
                let imagesJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                let images : NSArray = imagesJSON["images"] as! NSArray
                let temp : NSArray = images[0] as! NSArray
                var tempString64 : String = temp[0] as! String
                // I found a question on this site that said that the string should be of length multiple of 4, the following does that.
                let remainder = tempString64.count % 4
                if remainder > 0 {
                    tempString64 = tempString64.padding(toLength: tempString64.count + 4 - remainder,
                                                  withPad: "=",
                                                  startingAt: 0)
                }
                //check if string is not nil
                print(tempString64)

                let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: tempString64)
                let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded!)

               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myImageView.image = decodedimage
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Tail of tempString64

```
wBr9KavclvUrxPlNp6ircQ5qNLTDfe/Sr8Vvj L9KqS0BbEM2AKz2rXmt8j736VRNr/ALX6UJEmcv3qnPSpRZ/N979Kn y8fe/SqKiZhNJV1rP/AGv0pPsf 1 lEkJlFhkYpAoQe9aH2Pj736VE1n/t/pTV7DRXjPzVpL0qGCy5yX/StEW2B979KLFrYzpadafxfhU8ltn L9Kktrbbu b07Uraktn/2Q==
```

Length of tempString64 is 13752

Comment: Use `Data` not `NSData` in Swift.  Have you compared the string that you get when you encode the data with the string that is stored in your database and the string you get back from your database?

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, I use Data now, still does not work. The strings are the same indeed.

Comment: Why are you using the line length option?

Comment: @Paulw11 I dont think it is necessary, but it looks a little bit nicer in the database.

Comment: Please show the length of `tempString64` and the tail of it.

Comment: @OOPer I added the information at the end of the question.

Comment: Base64 string should not contain spaces. Maybe your server is replacing `+` into space before saving. Replace all spaces into `+` and try.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks, it works now!

Comment: This sort of replacement happens when you unload Base64 string without properly escaping. Consider fixing your upload code, rather than replacing spaces in download code.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused by the `lineLength64Characters` option. If this option is specified you have to decode the data with option `ignoreUnknownCharacters`

```
let dataDecoded  = Data(base64Encoded: tempString64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

---

But it's much easier to omit all options. The database doesn't care about nice formatting anyway.

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString()

...

let dataDecoded  = Data(base64Encoded: tempString64)!
```

UPDATE:

Remove the padding code and get the encoded string safely. The API handles the padding for you.

Don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native type safe types. And **never ever** use `.mutableContainers` particularly you assign the value to an **im**mutable constant. The option is pointless in Swift.

```
 if let data = data {
    do {
        if let imagesJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
           let images = imagesJSON["images"] as? [Any],
           let temp = images.first as? [String],
           let tempString64 = temp.first {

           print(tempString64)

           let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: tempString64)
           let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded!)

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.myImageView.image = decodedimage
           }
       }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I found the culprit: when I looked more carefully at tempString64, I saw a parenthesis at the end. I am not sure, but is there supposed to be a parenthesis in a base64 ?

Comment: Here is by the way the end of the string: lRt/x7j61CE9ii33ce9TRE5qFvun61LF1rSWwkWp ErKH3WrVn 5WSPutRS2Ie5oWXQmrsXLNnnpVKy6GrsP3m/Cs57s0RTk5mINWR/qV pqtJ/rjVkf6lfqaJbDGn/WH6U Ind NNP sP0pYvvD61LBi3f uVe3pWdeqqzEKAPpWjd/69az77/XH6VtS2M3sURS0gpa2Mz//Z)

Comment: I removed the lineLength option and added .ignoreUnknownCharacters just to be sure, but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: It looks like a String Interpolation mistake. Do you use the string in the form `"\(strBase64)"` and have an extraneous closing parenthesis like `"\(strBase64))"`?

Comment: Yes you are right :) I had an extra parenthesis there. Fixed it, but still dataDecoded nil :(

Comment: The en-/decoding without options and with balancing options `lineLength64Characters / ignoreUnknownCharacter` is supposed to work. The error reason must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I will continue looking for the bug

Comment: Could you look at my update in the question? I am really stuck.